# Maximum update depth exceeded when trying to access selectedFlatRows from Table(Child) compont to parent compntt while using useState inside useEffect

Tags: reactjs, react-native, react-hooks

My Question is how to send data from table ie selected row data from child to parent component

```
useEffect(()=>{
        setSelectedRows(selectedFlatRows);//here setSelectedRows is 
                                          //const [selectedRows,setSelectedRows] = useState([]); 
                                          //
    },[selectedFlatRows])
```

Commenting above code in child Table component resolves the error but not able to send selected row data to parent component.

Iam using react-table library for table creation

Answer (score 0):

You create infinite loop , what causes this issue?

useEffect invokes the setSelectedRows method and updates the value of the selectedRows Hook
After that, React re-renders the UI to display the updated value of setSelectedRows
Furthermore, since useEffect runs on every change in rowSelectedRows, it re-invokes the setSelectedRows function
Since the above steps occur on every render, this causes your app to crash

try use something like this :

```
useEffect(()=>{
        setSelectedRows(selectedFlatRows);
},[])
```

This tell react to execute setSelectedRows Once

Comment: used above code but on checkbox Selection no data is getting propogated to parent component since we are not passing any dependency

Comment: add more code, your problem not clear for me ..

Comment: https://codesandbox.io/s/sleepy-merkle-wcrl8o?file=/src/App.js

Comment: Iam trying to achieve above functionality just want selected rows from child component to parent component but in sandbox environment its working fine

Comment: The example code is not using selectedFlatRows directly, it is using 
    setSelection(selectedFlatRows.map((row) => row.original));  You can try that.